Log4J2.xml file is not generating a log file
I'm having an issue with my Log4J2.xml file. It is placed in the resources folder. It seems that my log4j2.xml file is literally being ignored by Springboot. Attached is the XML configurations.
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="logs/app.log">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

I've tried multiple configuration changes however it doesn't appear to be working.

This configuration works for me. Please show your build.gradle and where you place log4j2.xml and what is it's name really - is it log4J2.xml or log4j2.xml ?

You could try add this log4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml to your properties. In case the default is looking somewhere else

@Alex I'm not using build.gradle, I'm using pom.xml/Maven

@AndrewJohnson your configuration is good and it works. So the reason should be in something else. I'd like compare you environment with mine, that is why I asked for build script (using pom.xml is ok) and resource folder in you project. In pom you should have dependency to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2 and log4j2.xml file should be inside src/main/resource directory. If these points checked we will think what else it can be

@Alex I'm seeing the following error message, I think this may be because of a dependency conflict:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J: Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@163e4e87]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@56de5251]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@163e4e87]

Yes, you must remove the logback dependency, see this tutorial, the part concerning log4j. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging Fortunately the example is in maven syntax
